# How to avoid including root directory in every asset in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I write `<?php echo $this->Url->build(['/'); ?>` before any CSS or JS link in View files of CakePHP 3.1. Is there any way to get rid of this technique. For example, in `../src/template/test/index.ctp`

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->Url->build('/'); ?>images/seointro_logo.png" alt="logo">
```

I want that each link should work with writing the root directory. I see all files works without this code in webroot but not from src.

Comment: You can avoid problems like that by starting with the blog tutorial in the official documentation. http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples.html :) Or at least by reading about the HTML helper 
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html

Comment: check this please https://sarwarhossain.com/2010/03/16/how-to-cakephp-in-a-sub-directory-access-it-from-root-using-htaccess/

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->Url->build('/'); ?>images/seointro_logo.png" alt="logo">
```

Into this:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image('/images/seointro_logo.png', ['alt' => 'logo']); ?>
```

As burzum said, you should check about the HTML Helpers that CakePHP provides:
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I am looking for a solution so that I dont need to touch in these lines. That means keeping what the html developer did. i.e.-

<img src="images/seointro_logo.png" alt="logo">

So, that links can work correctly without writing any html helper or build.

Answer (score 0):

Use html helpers

```
<?= $this -> Html -> image('image.png', ['alt' => 'logo']); ?> // img/image.png

<?= $this -> Html -> script('Pages', ['block' => true])?> // js/Pages.js

<?= $this -> Html -> css('pages', ['block' => true]); ?> //css/pages.css
```

don´t forget add respective **fetch** in your layouts files:

```
<?= $this -> fetch('css') ?>
<?= $this -> fetch('script') ?>
```

if you change name of defauls folders, you must change this in **config/app.php**

```
'App' => [
    ...
    'webroot' => 'webroot',
    'imageBaseUrl' => 'img/', //<--- change img/ to yourImagesFolder/
    'cssBaseUrl' => 'css/',   //<--- change css/ to yourCssFolder/
    'jsBaseUrl' => 'js/',     //<--- change js/ to yourJsFolder/
    ....

],
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I am looking for a solution so that I dont need to touch in these lines. That means keeping what the html developer did. i.e.-

<img src="images/seointro_logo.png" alt="logo">

So, that links can work correctly without writing any html helper or build.